# convert a string (43677) to date format in SQL(Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How to convert a string (43677) to date in SQL(Redshift)?  (I'm trying to convert strings, which are number format of any particular date in excel)

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details. For example, what date would you expect `43677` to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what day you want, but I think:

```
select dateadd(day, 43677, '1899-12-30')
```

This interprets the value as an Excel date.  It produce 2019-07-31.

Comment: The use of 1899-12-30 rather than a more obvious 1899-12-31 accounts for a mistake in Excel whereas Excel considers 1900-02-29 to be a valid date even though there was no leap year in 1900. (Test this in Excel by typing the number 60 in a cell and then setting the format to short date).  This function in the approved answer works for most dates, but is off by one for numbers 0-59 and the handling of 60 is up to you.